# how $i++ is used here to find index of the correct array element

Tags: php, sql, multidimensional-array

If the cart array is empty its taking the item id and that displaying quantity as 1 . if not its getting into foreach loop and if that item is already in array array_splice takes place there . How $i++ and $i-1 for offset position is working here . whats is the logic

```
if (isset($_POST["pid"])) {
    $pid = $_POST["pid"];
    $wasfound = false;
    $i = 0;
    if ( ! isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
        $_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(
            0 => array(
                "item_id" => $pid,
                "quantity" => 1
            )
        );
    } else {
        foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {
            $i++;
            while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
                if ($key == "item_id" && $value == $pid) {
                    array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i-1, 1, array(
                        array(
                            "item_id" => $pid,
                            "quantity" => $each_item['quantity'] + 1
                        )
                    ));
                    $wasfound = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if ($wasfound == false) {
            array_push($_SESSION["cart_array"], array(
                "item_id" => $pid,
                "quantity" => 1
            ));
        }
    }
    header("location: cart.php"); 
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The $i keeps track of the index of the array that the for loop is currently processing.  It would be similar to writing the foreach as:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_SESSION['cart_array']);$i++){
    ...
}
```

The code uses the $i so it knows which index the element that is found is at within the $_SESSION['cart_array'] so it can splice it out.  Since they increment the $i (with $i++) at the start of the for loop, they need to decrement it when an element is found ($i-1).  Placing the $i++ line at the bottom of the for loop will eliminate the need for the decrement, and then the $i-1 can just be replaced with $i in the array_splice method.

You can read more about the array_splice method here http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php.  Notice that it requires an index (offset).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  It doesn't return anything.  It is just a variable holding the value of a number and as the code goes through each element in the $_SESSION['cart_array'] array, it increments from 0 to 1, 1 to 2, etc. whenever the code runs $i++.  When the code runs $i-1, it decrements it, i.e. 2 to 1, 1 to 0, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you read the manual on [array_splice](http://php.net/array-splice), you will see that the **offset** parameter isn't the key (*or index*) of an array element.

> If offset is positive then the start of removed portion is at that offset from the beginning of the input array. If offset is negative then it starts that far from the end of the input array.

Rather it is the position of the element in the array. In other words, `$i` represents the position of the element in the array here, and not the key of that element.

So in the following code...

```
$arr = ['foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 'quix'];
array_splice($arr, 1, 1);
var_dump($arr);
```

Would give you...

```
array(1) {
  ["foo"]=>
  string(3) "bar"
}
```

The rest of the logic is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Thank you all for your explanations